# Tokenizer in CountVectorizer runs multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text-mining, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

When python runs CountVectorizer, it calls tokenizer more then 1 time, to be precise-many many times, so the following code runs like this:

split-space

stem tokens

filter tokens

split-space

stem tokens

filter tokens

split-space

...

That makes the code runing too slow. I can't figure out why is vectorizer running like that, and how to prevent it and speed up the code?

```
#import stop_words dictionary    
dict=[]
with open("Stopwords.txt") as f:
    for word in f:
        dict.append(word.replace("\n",""))

#import stem dictionary
d = {}
with open("Stem rečnik.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, val = line.split(":")
       d[re.compile(key)] = val.replace("\n","")
    def custom_tokenizer(text):
            #split- space
            tokens = ' '.join(text).split()

    #   stem tokens
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        for key, val in d.items():
                if re.match(key, token):
                    tokens[i] = val

    #filter tokens
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if len(token)>=3]
    return tokens

cv=CountVectorizer(tokenizer= custom_tokenizer,analyzer ='word',encoding='utf-8',min_df=0, max_df=1.0, stop_words=frozenset(dict))

post_text_trainCV= cv.fit_transform(post_text_train)
```

I checked, problem is not in tokenizer function, it runs like it should, but when i run last line it calls tokenizer multiple times.

Comment: does the `custom_tokenizer` function work? Also in the function why are you joining the text and then splitting them? And how do you know its the tokenizer slowing down the process?

Comment: it works, i tried it on a piece of text. I did that to make a flat list of tokens not a list of list that contains a words for each sentence.

Comment: i tried it with this: text= ['lovin intesa','banke inteza','bankari intese','works csoidcn'] and did each part 2 times.

Comment: What is `d`? Is it an id-word dictionary?

Comment: @ClockSlave d is a dictionary. I probaly should add that to the code?

Comment: yes, you should. else I won't be able to run the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152646/discussion-between-clock-slave-and-hope94).

Comment: I added it. I guess now it's a problem in tokenizer not in count vectorizer itself. Otherwise, in my example above it would did every part only one time.